# Can't get hook_field_attach_view_alter to set the value of the field

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I'm using some hook code I got from [Drupal 7 show empty fields](http://ygerasimov.com/show-empty-fields) in order to show all of the empty fields on my node when viewing it. I would like to put a simple `-` as the displayed value when the field is empty.

```
function mymodule_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
    // other stuff clipped...
    $output[$field_name] = array(
        '#theme' => 'field',
        '#title' => $instance['label'],
        '#label_display' => 'inline',
        '#field_type' => $field['type'],
        '#field_name' => $field_name,
        '#bundle' => $node->type,
        '#object' => $node,
        '#items' => array(),
        '#entity_type' => 'node',
        '#weight' => $display['weight'],
        0 => array('#markup' => '-'),
    );
}
```

I pulled the code from the linked page above and just changed the one line at the end that has `#markup`. As far as I can tell from the api docs, this code should work, but nothing that I put into that `#markup` value shows up.

All of the empty fields DO show up, it's just that the value shown is empty instead of `-` or `blah` or `foo`, because I've tried those as well. :)

How do I set the value to display when I use [`hook_field_attach_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7)?

Comment: Did you find a way to get this working? It has been a while butI am facing exactly the same problem at the moment and hope that you might help me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer: the key "#items" in the output array needs to have an array with an array as the value - not just the array:

```
$output[$field_name] = array(
    '#theme' => 'field',
    '#title' => $instance['label'],
    '#label_display' => 'above',
    '#field_type' => $field['type'],
    '#field_name' => $field_name,
    '#bundle' => $node->type,
    '#object' => $node,
    '#items' => array(),
    '#entity_type' => 'node',
    '#weight' => $display['weight'],
    0 => array('#markup' => '&nbsp;'),
  );
```

becomes

```
$output[$field_name] = array(
    '#theme' => 'field',
    '#title' => $instance['label'],
    '#label_display' => 'above',
    '#field_type' => $field['type'],
    '#field_name' => $field_name,
    '#bundle' => $node->type,
    '#object' => $node,
    '#items' => array(array()),
    '#entity_type' => 'node',
    '#weight' => $display['weight'],
    0 => array('#markup' => '&nbsp;'),
  );
```